# How to pass variables and then display the results?

Tags: variable

Is there a plugin, technique, or combination of plugins/techniques that will allow me to do the following?

---

My channels are like this:

Parent: Product

Children: Colour, Size, Style, etc.

---

A search form with user-selectable fields such as these (or indeed hard-coded navigation menu links) - some of the fields are relationship fields:

Product

Colour

Size

Style

Min Price

Max Price

Stock status

---

..which would presumably result in a string such as ?size=M&min-price=100&stock-status=Y (or perhaps /medium/100/Y)

---

And then a results page with logic such as this:

{if

product="product" AND product_colour="colour" AND product_size="size" etc.

}

{/if}

---

Also, apparently I would need the conditional to parse early, as I'm displaying the resultant data in a grid that depends on a Switch tag to add closing divs to rows.

Would be v grateful for any pointers, however general they may be.

Comment: Exist conditional modules capable to parse early: switchee and ifelse. Look at http://devot-ee.com.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Wires](https://github.com/croxton/Wires) addon. Mark, who created switchee and ifelse, is yet writing the docs and improving the code, but, by my tests, it's stable.

Comment: Thank you - that looks promising, though seems I might have to learn stash and low search at the same time - might take me a while...

Comment: I believe you don't need stash, but just to mix @low answer and mine.

Comment: Thanks Robson - as below, in the end I found Refine did what I wanted off-the-shelf, though Wires certainly looks interesting and I'll keep it in mind for the future. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically just looking for a way to filter down channel entries based on a filled out form. Take a look at either Solspace's [Super Search](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/super_search/) or my own [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search). Both should be up for the job.

Comment: Thanks - I noticed both of those modules and did wonder if they might be appropriate. Out of interest, would the new built-in Template Routes function address my problem?

Comment: Not really. The Routes look at URI segments. If you submit a form using GET, you won't get those values in the URI, but in the query string instead. So you'd still need a module of some sort to catch the form submit and change it to a segmented URI. That's why you're probably better off using one of the before mentioned search add-ons.

Comment: After some further hunting I found that the Reefine module does pretty much exactly what I need. Thanks v much for your help, and I'll certainly consider Low Search should I need to do something similar next time (btw thanks for your Yearly Archives module - was perfect for another issue I had.)